# Xcode full screen pdf generator

Tags: swift, xcode, pdf, share

I am working on an Xcode 10 project (Swift 4.2), and I want to generate a pdf of view content. I have seen this done with dynamic text, etc., but I would like to generate a screenshot of the view and save it in the application. What is the easiest way to do this?

I can set up an HTML form, but since the screen contains images and labels already arranged in the desired format, it would be nice if there was a way to save view contents as an image and create a pdf of that image. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you can set up an HTML page, your question is not necessary a Xcode PDF generator but "How to convert html to pdf?". And for that, you can use jsPDF's `.html()` and `html2canvas 1.0.0-alpha.12`.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js" 
        integrity="sha384-NaWTHo/8YCBYJ59830LTz/P4aQZK1sS0SneOgAvhsIl3zBu8r9RevNg5lHCHAuQ/"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<!-- html2canvas 1.0.0-alpha.11 or higher version is needed -->

<script>
    function onClick() {
        let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
        pdf.html(document.body, {
            callback: function () {
                pdf.save('test.pdf');
                window.open(pdf.output('bloburl')); // To debug.
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```